# Can't remove cell spacing between cells in table html css

Tags: html, css, html-table, datatable

I am trying to create a table using html and css for my webpage. But the problem is that I can't get it to work, there is an obvious grid between cells in my table that I can't get rid of. I have looked for hours on google for a solution without any improvements. Here is an example of what I get with my current code: [image: Text]. As you can see, between each header cell, there is an obvious line. Same goes with the rest of the body cells if I change color there. Here is some styling for the rest of the page if necessary:

```
<style media="screen">
    html, body
    {
      height: 100%;
    }

    body
    {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #292929;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    nav
    {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0%;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 319px;
      display: table;
      /* margin: 0 auto; */
      /* transform: translateY(-50%); */

      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-left: 10px;

      /* added */
      table-layout: fixed;
    }

    nav a
    {
      width: 70px;
      position: relative;
      /* width: 33.333%; */
      display: table-cell;
      text-align: center;
      color: #949494;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      transition: 0.2s ease color;
    }

    nav a:before, nav a:after
    {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 50%;
      transform: scale(0);
      transition: 0.2s ease transform;
    }

    nav a:before
    {
      top: 0;
      left: 10px;
      width: 6px;
      height: 6px;
    }

    nav a:after
    {
      top: 5px;
      left: 18px;
      width: 4px;
      height: 4px
    }

    nav a:nth-child(1):before
    {
      background-color: red;
    }

    nav a:nth-child(1):after
    {
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    nav a:nth-child(2):before
    {
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    nav a:nth-child(2):after
    {
      background-color: orange;
    }

    nav a:nth-child(3):before
    {
      background-color: #00e2ff;
    }

    nav a:nth-child(3):after
    {
      background-color: #89ff00;
    }

    nav a:nth-child(4):before
    {
      background-color: blue;
    }

    nav a:nth-child(4):after
    {
      background-color: #00e2ff;
    }

    nav a:nth-child(5):before
    {
      background-color: purple;
    }

    nav a:nth-child(5):after
    {
      background-color: palevioletred;
    }

    nav a:nth-child(6):before
    {
      background-color: #ff008c;
    }

    nav a:nth-child(6):after
    {
      background-color: pink;
    }

    nav a:nth-child(7):before
    {
      background-color: purple;
    }

    nav a:nth-child(7):after
    {
      background-color: red;
    }



    #indicator
    {
      position: absolute;
      left: 4%;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 30px;
      height: 3px;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      transition: 0.2s ease left;
    }

    nav a:hover
    {
      color: #fff;
    }

    nav a:hover:before, nav a:hover:after
    {
      transform: scale(1);
    }

    nav a:nth-child(1):hover ~ #indicator
    {
      background: linear-gradient(130deg, red, yellow);
    }

    nav a:nth-child(2):hover ~ #indicator
    {
      left: calc(4% + 100%/7);
      background: linear-gradient(130deg, yellow, orange);
    }

    nav a:nth-child(3):hover ~ #indicator
    {
      left: calc(4% + 100%/7 * 2);
      background: linear-gradient(130deg, #00e2ff, #89ff00);
    }

    nav a:nth-child(4):hover ~ #indicator
    {
      left: calc(4% + 100%/7 * 3);
      background: linear-gradient(130deg, blue, #00e2ff);
    }

    nav a:nth-child(5):hover ~ #indicator
    {
      left: calc(4% + 100%/7 * 4);
      background: linear-gradient(130deg, purple, palevioletred);
    }

    nav a:nth-child(6):hover ~ #indicator
    {
      left: calc(4% + 100%/7 * 5);
      background: linear-gradient(130deg, #ff008c, pink);
    }

    nav a:nth-child(7):hover ~ #indicator
    {
      left: calc(4% + 100%/7 * 6);
      background: linear-gradient(130deg, purple, red);
    }

    #back_btn {
      display: block;
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      padding: 10px 14px;
      margin: 20px;
      color: #fff;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: #000;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      z-index: 125;
    }



    </style>
```

And here is the main styling for the table:

```
<style media="screen"> /* table */
    /* schedule css */

    .schedule_holder {
      /* center */
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

      overflow: auto;
      height: 70%;
      margin-top: 4%;

      border-radius: 5px;

      /* box-shadow:
      1px 1px 0 #444,
      2px 2px 0 #444,
      3px 3px 0 #444,
      4px 4px 0 #444,
      5px 5px 0 #444,
      6px 6px 0 #444,
      5px 5px 15px #999; */
      /* center end */
    }

    /* rest of table */


    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 2rem;
    }

    table {
      text-align: left;
      position: relative;
      border-collapse: collapse;

      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    thead {
      background: #565656;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }
    th, td {
      padding: 10px;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    tr th {
      /* background: #565656; */
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      color: white;
    }
    tr.red th {
      background: red;
      color: white;
    }
    tr.green th {
      background: green;
      color: white;
    }
    tr.purple th {
      background: purple;
      color: white;
    }
    th {
      background: white;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0; /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */
      /* box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); */
    }
    </style>
```

Along with the html body:

```
<body>
    <nav id="days_nav">
      <a href="#">Måndag</a>
      <a href="#">Tisdag</a>
      <a href="#">Onsdag</a>
      <a href="#">Torsdag</a>
      <a href="#">Fredag</a>
      <a href="#">Lördag</a>
      <a href="#">Söndag</a>
      <div id="indicator"></div>
    </nav>



    <div class="schedule_holder" id="monday_holder">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Lektion</th>
            <th>Lärare</th>
            <th>Start</th>
            <th>Slut</th>
            <th>Inställd?</th>
            <th>Information</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Lorem.</td>
            <td>Ullam.</td>
            <td>Vel.</td>
            <td>At.</td>
            <td>Quis.</td>
            <td>Quis.</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Quas!</td>
            <td>Velit.</td>
            <td>Quisquam?</td>
            <td>Rerum?</td>
            <td>Iusto?</td>
            <td>Quis.</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Voluptates!</td>
            <td>Fugiat?</td>
            <td>Alias.</td>
            <td>Doloribus.</td>
            <td>Veritatis.</td>
            <td>Quis.</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Maiores.</td>
            <td>Ab.</td>
            <td>Accusantium.</td>
            <td>Ullam!</td>
            <td>Eveniet.</td>
            <td>Quis.</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript: go_back();" id="back_btn">Tillbaka</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
  </body>
```

I hope somebody is able to help me. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
The main style was copied from [here](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/PrJdxb), where it did work without any problems, but as soon as I copied it into my code it started to have some troubles, the same goes with other tables I have tried to create.

Comment: Is there any chance that you zoomed in/out your browser. Chrome does this to me all the time..

Comment: Yes I have been zoomed in but zooming out doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copy exactly what you have for css and html, I don't see the white lines. BUT... I think it may have something to do with the last style you have in the table stylesheet.

```
th {
      background: white;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0; /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */
      /* box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); */
}
```

What happens if you change the background color to a bright color like red or orange? Do the grid line colors change?

EDIT:

I looked at the link you provided. I was able to see the issue in Safari but only when I zoom. I believe it is rendering issue caused by `position: absolute` and perhaps the transform on `<div class="schedule_holder">`
Updating the styles for that element worked for me.

```
.schedule_holder {
   overflow: auto;
   height: 70%;
   margin-top: 4%;
   border-radius: 5px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work, the problem is still the same.

Comment: What browser are you using? I checked it in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. And I didn't see the issue. It's obviously there in your screenshot, though.

Comment: I have tested on Opera mainly but chrome and safari as well. I can provide with a link to the entire page, I will make an edit on the post and attach the link.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt look like a real border, but perhaps a rendering/rounding issue (half pixel thing). Make sure you havent zoomed in/out in your browser, and resize your window to see if it persist.

You could try to set a red background color on the body or table, to see if that white line turns red. If so it would mean there is a space rendered in between, which you could get rid of by setting a background color on the tr instead of thead/th.

Comment: I did try to change table color and it did change the color of the lines like so: [link](http://elvigo.com/vigor/services/schedule/Screenshot2.png). That changed the linecolor so I tried to change the color of the tr instead of the thead and th: `thead tr {
      background: #565656;
    }`. That resulted in [link](http://elvigo.com/vigor/services/schedule/Screenshot2.png), as you can see the lines are smaller but is still there, and they are more visable if you apply to all tr's: [link](http://elvigo.com/vigor/services/schedule/Screenshot4.png)

Comment: Did you try isolating the table by disabling ALL styling and reapplying only styling of the table? You might find something is interfering (overflows/transforms/etc). And try putting it on a page without any other element, in case something higher up the tree is causing it.